# How do I undock Chrome F12 developer tools?

Tags: google-chrome, developer-tools

I'm using Chrome 40.0.2214.94 m on Windows 7.

When you press F12 for Developer Tools, it remains docked to the main Chrome window. There is no way to Undock it to its own separate window. This is a new PC and I could do this on my old machine. When verifying with a colleague, he gets a button to undock it to a separate window. All I have is "Dock to Main Window" which just toggles between it being docked to the right or the bottom of the main window.

How do I get the F12 developer tools out into their own window?

Comment: Found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10023640/how-to-reposition-chrome-developer-tools

Long hold - who knew.

Comment: Or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20220090/undock-chrome-developer-tools

Answer (score 3):

Long Press the undock button, the icon will show.